# HTACCESS- Rewriting URL

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

How can I convert this url-

```
mywebsite.com/{value}
```

to-

```
mywebsite.com/future.php?name={value}
```

Request someone to please explain the procedure of rewriting.

Comment: If you want to convert to the lengthier format you would remove the rewrite rules from your htaccess file. *Explaining* mod-rewrite would require a very lengthy answer, one too broad for Stack Overflow.

Comment: There are about 6657347689 questions with answers to this topic alone here on SO. None of all those answers helped you to solve your task? _Why not?_ And why should the 6657347690th answer now make a difference? Please research before asking, read the official documentation of the tools you use and also check the "Related" section to the right ;-)

Comment: @arkascha After even lots of modifications, the code provided by other to do as told by you does not work. Need a specific answer because of this issue

Comment: Hm, interesting. Would you mind sharing that code you tried and modified, so that we can see what your actual issue is? Thanks!